# Reactjs useMemo hook behaviour like componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use useMemo like useEffect with componentDidMount behaviour but my useMemo is acting just like componentWillMount and is rendering unstoppably .

Here is the code:

```
useMemo(() => {
    console.log('rendered');
    fetch(`backend url`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userId: userInf._id,
        fields: ['readers', 'followers', 'news', 'podcast', 'video'],
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setUserArticles(res.news);
      })
      .catch((err) => err);
  }, [userArticles]);
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: `[userArticles]` tells it to re-run every time `userArticles` changes, and since the hook itself changes `userArticles` it will trigger a re-run. You can try using an empty array instead.

Comment: But as far as I know useMemo need to look at the specific value to track any differences. am I wrong?

Comment: Just use `useEffect` to issue side-effects like data fetching, it's what it is for, `useMemo` is for memoizing values. Additionally, you can't update a value that is in a hook's dependency array, this will cause render looping.

Comment: @user14587589 Depends on what behaviour you want. `useMemo` should also return a value that you can use, otherwise you're better off using `useEffect`.

Comment: I have user profile and every time user visits this route it fires this Ajax request and re-renders component and I want to avoid it and only re-render it if user information changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The `useMemo` hook is intended for computing and memoizing a value. It appears your hook callback is actually updating *some* state, and this state or value is also declared in the hook'd dependency array, which after updating and rerendering, will run the hook callback again and update state... creating an infinite loop.

## Solution

If you want to issue a side-effect only once when the component mounts, like `componentDidMount`, then use an `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('rendered');
  fetch(`backend url`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userId: userInf._id,
      fields: ['readers', 'followers', 'news', 'podcast', 'video'],
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setUserArticles(res.news);
    })
    .catch((err) => err);
}, []);
```

[Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.
>
> If you pass an empty array (`[]`), the props and state inside the effect
> will always have their initial values. While passing `[]` as the second
> argument is closer to the familiar `componentDidMount` and
> `componentWillUnmount` mental model, there are usually better solutions
> to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React
> defers running `useEffect` until after the browser has painted, so doing
> extra work is less of a problem.